# Invalid ALB listenerArn in function Error when deploying AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm getting following error when deploying AWS lambda function. Any suggestions to resolve this?

```
Warning: Invalid configuration encountered
  at 'functions.handler.events.0.alb.listenerArn': must match pattern "^arn:aws[\w-]*:elasticloadbalancing:.+:listener\/app\/[\w-]+\/([\w-]+)\/([\w-]+)$"

Learn more about configuration validation here: http://slss.io/configuration-validation

Error:
Invalid ALB listenerArn in function "handler".
```

The ALB arn is set as follows in the serverless.yml

```
functions:   handler:
    handler: com.BIS.dev.trigger.Handler
    events:
      - alb:
          listenerArn: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234:listener/my-dev-app-load-balancer/8347979fhf2
          priority: 1
          conditions:
            path: /trigger/invoke
```

Comment: The ARN you provided is form `targetgroup`, not listener.

Comment: Tried with listener as well. Same result